# How to call method in UIPickerView subclass from another view controller?

Tags: swift3, subclass, uipickerview

I have a `UIPickerView` that I am subclassing, which works great.  However, I have a method that I need to call to "reset" the UIPicker from the UIViewController in which it's being viewed.  However, it never fires.  How do I call `func resetPicker()` from another view controller?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ScoreClockPicker: UIPickerView {

    //PickerView
    let timerMinutesArray = Array(00...20)
    let timerSecondsArray = Array(00...59)
    let periodArray = ["1st", "2nd", "3rd", "OT", "SO"]

    //Picker return values
    var numberOfRowsInComponentReturnValue = 0
    var titleForRowReturnValue             = ""
    var widthForComponentReturnValue       = ""


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.delegate   = self
        self.dataSource = self

    }

    func resetPicker() {
        print("resetPicker")

        self.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
        self.selectRow(0, inComponent: 1, animated: true)
        self.selectRow(0, inComponent: 3, animated: true)

    }
}

extension ScoreClockPicker: UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        if component == 0 {

            numberOfRowsInComponentReturnValue =  periodArray.count

        } else if component == 1 {

            numberOfRowsInComponentReturnValue = timerMinutesArray.count

        } else if component == 2 {

            numberOfRowsInComponentReturnValue = 1

        } else if component == 3 {

            numberOfRowsInComponentReturnValue = timerSecondsArray.count

        }

        return numberOfRowsInComponentReturnValue

    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 4

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        var componentWidth = 0

        if component == 0 {

            componentWidth = 140

        } else if component == 1 {

            componentWidth = 40

        } else if component == 2 {

            componentWidth = 30

        } else if component == 3 {

            componentWidth = 40
        }

        return CGFloat(componentWidth)
    }


}

extension ScoreClockPicker: UIPickerViewDelegate {

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        print("didSelectRow")
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        if component == 0 {

            titleForRowReturnValue =  periodArray[row]

        } else if component == 1 {

            titleForRowReturnValue =  String(describing: timerMinutesArray[row])

        } else if component == 2 {

            titleForRowReturnValue =  ":"

        } else if component == 3 {

            titleForRowReturnValue =  String(format: "%02d",timerSecondsArray[row])
        }

        return titleForRowReturnValue

    }

}
```

EDIT:

The following doesn't work from the viewController calling the `ScoreClockPicker`:

```
import UIKit

class ScoreClockViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var resetButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var okButton: UIButton!

   var picker: ScoreClockPicker?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        //Hide the Navigation Bar
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }

    //@IBOutlet
    @IBAction func reset(_ sender: Any) {
        print("reset")

        picker?.resetPicker() //Call the ScoreClockPicker

//        picker?.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
//        picker?.selectRow(0, inComponent: 1, animated: true)
//        picker?.selectRow(0, inComponent: 3, animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func ok(_ sender: Any) {
    }


}
```

Comment: Add the code where you are creating object of `ScoreClockPicker`. Means add the code of your ViewController.

Comment: @NiravD, see edit above.  I've tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: Where you have initialized this `picker` object show us the code of that too, Also reset is button action?

Comment: @NiravD See the edit above.

Comment: Look like you haven't initialized the picker yet. So it is nil

Comment: I'm not seeing any place where an object reference is being assigned to the `picker` variable.  How does it become something other than nil?

Comment: In the view contoller where I actually have the UIPIckerObject, are you sayng I have to     @IBOutlet weak var picker: ScoreClockPicker!, I didn't think I had to do this but it makes sense now.  Thanks, all is well.

Comment: @PaulS. Are You setting `ScoreClockPicker` as class for `UIPickerView` in storyboard?

Comment: @NiravD, yes, I'm setting the custom class on the UIPickerView

Comment: @PaulS. Then it should be like `@IBOutlet var picker: ScoreClockPicker!` or `@IBOutlet weak var picker: ScoreClockPicker!`, because you have not set the outlet your function is not getting called.

Comment: @NiravD Absolutely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code you haven't initialized the `picker` object that you are trying to use in button action. So simply initialized the `picker` before using it.

If you are making outlet of `ScoreClockPicker` then

```
@IBOutlet var picker: ScoreClockPicker!
```

OR you can initialized `picker` in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.picker = ScoreClockPicker()
```

Comment: @PaulS. Welcome mate :)